# Mount tmpfs when using docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-stack

When deploying a standalone container I can mount /dev/shm as a tmpfs with custom options as follows:

```
docker run --name my-container -v /dev/shm --tmpfs /dev/shm:rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,size=90g my-image
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do the same thing when deploying a container over a swarm using `docker stack deploy`. There does not appear to be any relevant information in the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#tmpfs). With the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  master:
  image: "my-image"
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - type: tmpfs
     target: /dev/shm
```

`/dev/shm` is mounted with default options. How can I mount `/dev/shm` with the options `(rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,size=90g)` using `docker stack deploy`?

Comment: I know this question is old, but were you able to solve it? I am using docker swarm and I am running jenkins in the swarm. I want my workspace folder to be tmpfs for performance reasons and to avoid disk I/O (because ssd disks do not like to much write operations). But my build job wants to execute nodeJS in workspace what is currently not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#choosing-the---tmpfs-or---mount-flag), --tmpfs can only be used with **standalone** containers, for services use --mount:

> --tmpfs: Mounts a tmpfs mount without allowing you to specify any configurable options, and can only be used with **standalone containers**

Difference between --tmpfs and --mount described [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#differences-between---tmpfs-and---mount-behavior):

> - The --tmpfs flag does not allow you to specify any configurable options.
> - The **--tmpfs** flag **cannot** be used with **swarm services**. You must use --mount.

Comment: Thanks, but I think --mount is a command line parameter only and does not work when using a compose file (or at least is not documented). Furthermore, from the PR [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36720) it appears that it is not possible to mount a tmpfs with the exec option when using `--mount`